# Xcode build error "option '-p, --packages <packages...>' argument missing"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build, xcode14

I'm trying to build a react-native app and load it onto an iPhone simulator.

When I try to build with the Xcode (14.2) build button, it quickly fails and spits out the following error:

`option '-p, --packages <packages...>' argument missing`

When I try to build by running Metro bundler via 'npm react-native start' in my terminal and then following up with the option to "run on ios" by typing "i", it gets stuck for over an hour and counting (with no errors) on the following line:

`CreateBuildDirectory /Users/emidac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppTrackerTechnicalInterview-dzbptdkaecwmhlbdmrzuhgqtzjau/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/R`

Any help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED!

p.s. I already tried to clean the build folder, remove and reinstall node modules, retry pod install, restart xcode, restart my computer etc AND `npx react-native doctor` outputs 5 green checkmarks and no errors for iOS